RegQueryInfoKey and RegEnumKeyEx fails to get the correct number of subkeys
I have used RegQueryInfoKey and later RegEnumKeyEx in a function to enumerate through all the subkeys in a registry key, but this does not seem to work as the number of keys I am getting is not correct (around 10 subkeys are actually present in the registry while i am getting 3).
The program was in C++ like this:
    DWORD subkeyCount = 0;
    DWORD cbMaxSubKeyLen = 0;
    result = RegQueryInfoKeyW(hEnrollmentsKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subkeyCount, &cbMaxSubKeyLen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegCloseKey(hEnrollmentsKey);
        return sidAdded;
    }

Here I am getting the count as 3, The process is a service running with elevated privileges.
Edit: I have managed to get the correct number of subkeys after i gave the KEY_WOW64_64KEY permission but the RegEnumKeyEx still does not enumerate all the subkeys.

You are probably looking at the wrong registry key (see Registry Virtualization and 32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry).
